# Spring XML and java.util.regex.Pattern.compile ... not working?

Tags: java, regex, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Here is an extract from beans.xml:

```
<bean class="java.util.regex.Pattern" factory-method="compile">
    <constructor-arg value=".*some pattern.*"/>
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="{ T(java.util.regex.Pattern).DOTALL | T(java.util.regex.Pattern).CASE_INSENSITIVE }"/>
</bean>
```

For unknown reasing I get the following error while Spring framework loads:

```
2015-10-01 00:05:14 WARN  XmlWebApplicationContext:487 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.FilterFactoryBean#4': Cannot create inner bean  com.test.test_core.monitor.DocumentFieldRegexFilter#0' of type [com.test.test_core.monitor.DocumentFieldRegexFilter] while setting bean property 'targetObject'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.test.test_core.monitor.DocumentFieldRegexFilter#0#1' defined in file [c:\java\jetty\config\dev\spring-context\local-beans-1.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'util:list#719d35e8' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'util:list#719d35e8': Cannot create inner bean 'org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair#244e619a' of type [org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair] while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair#244e619a' defined in file [c:\java\jetty\config\dev\spring-context\local-beans-1.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'java.util.regex.Pattern#10ef5fa0' of type [java.util.regex.Pattern] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'java.util.regex.Pattern#10ef5fa0' defined in file [c:\java\jetty\config\dev\spring-context\local-beans-1.xml]: No matching factory method found: factory method 'compile(String,int)'. Check that a method with the specified name and arguments exists and that it is static.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
```

I don't understand why I get this error:

```
No matching factory method found: factory method 'compile(String,int)'
```

if there is exactly such a method according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

I am using Windows 7, java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I found the solution - SPeL was incorrect. I changed bitwise OR to simply plus and it worked (I know, it is not the same, but this is a different story). Moreover, I needed to add # (hashtag) at the beginning although according to Spring documentation it is not required:

```
<bean class="java.util.regex.Pattern" factory-method="compile">
    <constructor-arg value=".*some pattern.*"/>
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="#{ T(java.util.regex.Pattern).DOTALL + T(java.util.regex.Pattern).CASE_INSENSITIVE }"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Don't edit your question adding an answer in it. If you feel the need, you should add an answer with that code. You can then accept an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is a bit misleading. In fact, you are missing the `#` character at the beginning of your SpEL.

```
<bean class="java.util.regex.Pattern" factory-method="compile">
    <constructor-arg value=".*some pattern.*" />
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="#{T(java.util.regex.Pattern).DOTALL | T(java.util.regex.Pattern).CASE_INSENSITIVE}" />
</bean>
```

However, this won't work because SpEL does not currently support the bitwise OR `|` operator. There is an improvement request ([SPR-6254](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6254)), currently waiting for triage, about this (see the list of supported operators [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operators)).

You can create a work-around by providing your own factory method:

```
public final class PatternFactory {
    public static Pattern create(String regex) {
        return Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    }
}
```

with

```
<bean class="package.PatternFactory" factory-method="create">
    <constructor-arg value=".*some pattern.*" />
</bean>
```

Comment: One small amendment: bitwise OR, not XOR :)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found the answer. It turned out that it is a wrong message (bug?) in Spring. The problem was with wrongly evaluated SPEL expression. After correcting it everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Please show us the correct expression and how you determine that that was the cause.

Comment: SPeL does not handle | (bitwise OR) operator. I changed it to + and it started working: #{ (T(java.util.regex.Pattern).DOTALL + T(java.util.regex.Pattern).CASE_INSENSITIVE) }

Comment: Your current answer is pretty poor. Considering editing in the content you posted in your previous comment.